# How to loop through fields in a .NET MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC remote sharepoint app & have written code to export a ListItemCollection as JSON, without needing to know the field names.  How can I do the same for a custom model passed as formdata from the view to the controller? Here's a snippet of the JSON Export code, which shows what I'd like to do

```
foreach (ListItem oListItem in IndListItem)
{
    int fcount =oListItem.FieldValues.Keys.Count;
    for (int j = 0; j < fcount; j++)
    {                    
        fname= oListItem.FieldValues.Keys.ElementAt(j);
        fval = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(oListItem.FieldValues[fname].ToString());
    }
    json += '"' + fname + '"' + ":" + '"' + fval + '"' + ",";
}
```

I want to acheive something like

```
sp.ListItem oListItem = list.GetItemById(id);
foreach (xField in formdata)
{
    oListItem[xField] = formdata.getField(xField).ToString();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to generate JSON yourself.  You have a few options:

In your MVC action, return a JsonResult.

```
public ActionResult MyListAsJson() { 
   /* get list */
   return Json(IndListItem);
}
```

Use a [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var serializer = new JavascriptSerialzer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(IndListItem);
```

Other common alternatives include [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) and [Json.NET](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json)